# How to unit test code with ScheduledExecutorService and ScheduledFuture

Tags: java, unit-testing, concurrency, spock

I have this Java class:

```
public class Refresher {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = null;

    public void refresh(Supplier<String> supplier) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (scheduledFuture != null) {
                scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
            }

            scheduledFuture = executor.schedule(supplier::get, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I want to create a unit test that tests when subsequent calls of refresh are made, they get cancelled except for the last one that executes.

I run the code and this is how it behaves in practice but I need to have the unit test and I do not know how to do it.

My tests are written in Spock, I experimented with several things but none was successful.

A testable alternative that achieves the same is also welcome.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: I think you will need a constructor that lets you _inject_ a ScheduledExecutorService. Then your unit test can inject a _mock_ that lets the test verify that `refresh` calls the right methods in the right order, etc.

Comment: Actually, I support the idea of making dependencies injectable when they are needed for testing. In this case, it would however be possible to inject a supplier counting calls. That is a workaround, but Solomon's suggestion is fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject supplier which not only returns a string but also counts how often it was actually called. Make sure the test calls `refresh` multiple times within the 500 ms window, then make the test wait for more than 500 ms, say 700 ms. Finally, check that the supplier was called only a single time. That indirectly proves that all but one scheduled calls have actually been executed.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75539518

import spock.lang.Specification

class RefresherTest extends Specification {
  def "quick subsequent refresh calls are cancelled except for the last one"() {
    given:
    def refresher = new Refresher()
    int countCalled = 0
    def supplier = {
      countCalled++
      "supplied value"
    }

    when:
    refresher.refresh supplier
    refresher.refresh supplier
    refresher.refresh supplier
    sleep 700

    then:
    countCalled == 1

    cleanup:
    refresher.shutdown()
  }

  def "slow subsequent refresh calls are executed one by one"() {
    given:
    def refresher = new Refresher()
    int countCalled = 0
    def supplier = {
      countCalled++
      "supplied value"
    }

    when:
    refresher.refresh supplier
    sleep 700
    refresher.refresh supplier
    sleep 700
    refresher.refresh supplier
    sleep 700

    then:
    countCalled == 3

    cleanup:
    refresher.shutdown()
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_3_0&codez=eJzdVE1vEzEQve-vGHLaqMVNVUWFpCmHUqRKBSQ2nJHjnc2aOPbGH5sW1P-O411vmlACCLiQS1aeN_PezBu7omxB5wg5EsO0W35aUmNRE2N9QNWoC6HWZHU-HJ69HJ6-SBK-rJS2YCrFFkRQOSdZhYwXnFHLlUwSJqgx8AELjaZEPUVjAe8sytzADhS-JuB5C-itHGcLMG5mcOVQWtBNNjAqhAGq0X9JhkJg7msxrCwUSoMtETybBSWxl_ZDQYA5r1GOwuemuo5KYAIS11tlaT9guOdjykl7RUP9CQy6XOOqSvCQ2tSGx9Cjo_as1-JyqKlw2AvHD0n4W5dRTCeExPZi-b8QNgKxgvPBoGG1HetOaxM4beJMIJWu2hdmSmdztZZhNKGB4I_xO3DYHrxD5qyn8E7A7P6_MGQ70n8HPmzW2e-Y5ds7OYHnf_DrLvdnWlPiLBeEKcmc1t50ch0sVtqMD8IyVmLufAMRn6GuOcNfzHrjrNM_AU_5Ej9Kbp9AFU6yzdtCsnbe4ySp3ExwBnvvUtifSvOaWoSCSyrgR9Lb7VabreumQPzqZlzOBU5LjTT_Ljntjx8x7DV48eoSzO7R5jY4IcYbz1vJteJ5NDyNHV1kVnvey26l4jUz95KVWkn-xW9Paktu-t0l4QWk-3zPGsJ-C4F9QaR5c1OrHYZensB40XE4JIbSKGw0mqM9huFgcAzRM_L25vb2Jru-ev_uddZWfYiPzeO2t9vdNrHl6SLjdvG_AeOAMVs).

---

**Update:** Added a second feature method for the opposite test case.

Comment: That is possible, the downside is that the tests take 700ms and the second one 2.1s. While not terrible if there are a lot of those tests, I would suggest to go with the injection route and also making the delay configurable.

Comment: Yes, of course. If it was my own code, I would refactor it to use dependency injection for the executor. I also agree, that the timeout should be injectable to make it as short as possible for integration testing (no mocks). Imagine that the default was 25 or 60 s. I am not making this up. In my current customer's project I actually just met such a hard-coded 25 s timeout. It consumes 95% of the total unit test suite execution time and is to be refactored by the team ASAP.

Comment: @Paris Karagiannopoulos, maybe you want to take a look at Spock's [`MutableClock`](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M1/all_in_one.html#mutable-clock), which could come in handy in some situations (not necessarily here).